# C++ How to initialize array in struct of unknown size

Tags: c++11, data-structures

So I have this structure definition in my header file, inside this structure is an array of another structure. I want to read in the size of this array from a file, but I just can't figure out how.

```
struct Struct1
{
struct Struct2 sArry[];
};

//And then initialize sArry[] as a size read from file
inFile >> size;
Struct1->sArry[size];
```

Comment: You cannot do that. Your alternatives are to set a maximum size or to use `vector<Struct2>`.

Comment: Alrighty thanks, I'll just use vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the question, I will write the answer.

It is not possible to change the array sizes at runtime. Therefore, the two solutions I see are:

1. Use `vector<Struct2>` instead of `Struct2 sArry[]`. This might be a bit more inefficient but I it is not probably the bottleneck of your code.
2. Set a maximum size at compilation time `Struct2 sArry[MAXSIZE]`, defining MAXSIZE at will. This is memory inefficient and not very elegant.

**Note**: C++11 includes `std::array<type, size>` which is what you should use instead of C-style arrays.